# How to create a datepicker search in Dashboard in Angular14?Or, How to filter searchvalues by clicking on Datepicker?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, webapi

How to create a datepicker search in Dashboard in Angular14? Or, How to filter searchvalues by clicking on Datepicker?

Html:

```
<input type="date" style="width: 100%; height: 34px" (change)="SendDataonChange($event)"/>
```

ts:

```
 SendDataonChange(event: any) {
    debugger;
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    var $this = this;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      if (event.keyCode != 13) {
        $this.applySearchByDateFilter(event.target.value);
      }
    }, 500);
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="date" style="width: 100%; height: 34px" (change)="SendDataonChange($event)"/>
```

I expect results (dashoard records view) on the basis of clicking A particular date in datepicker

Answer (score 0):

do this work for you?

```
<input type="date" [ngModel] ="dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (change)="dt = $event">
```

Im showing you how you would convert your date to a desirable format (My guess is the format is not right for your service call).

Please let me know if it does not work, i am only answering your question based on my understanding